# Jupyter Notebook Pyspark in Yarn-Client Mode NameError 'sc' not defined

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm a beginner. When I ran Jupyter Notebook with a basic code, it showed a error like this:

```
     NameErr      Traceback (most recencall last)
    <ipython-input-1-67f48183a30b> in <module>()
    ----> 1 sc.master
    NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

and I used these command lines to enter Jutyper Notebook in Yarn-Client mode:

```
    tigerfish@master:~/桌面$ PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" HADOOP_CONF_IR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode client
```

```
and belows are errors and warnings
    [I 10:45:25.079 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret
    [I 10:45:25.139 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/tigerfish/桌面
    [I 10:45:25.139 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
    [I 10:45:25.139 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
    [I 10:45:25.139 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
    ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
    [I 10:45:43.265 NotebookApp] Kernel started: c6392ab5-ea7b-402e-ae26-6bc89e07791a
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment.
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateSubmitArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with a downgraded python2.7,  Hadoop 2.6.0, pyspark 1.4.0 ,jdk8

How can I get this problem solved? It's confusing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJjiH.png)

Answer (score 0):

it finally dawns on me that my launch code had a problem...A stupid problem..

Errors in Terminal showed:

```
[I 10:45:43.265 NotebookApp] Kernel started: c6392ab5-ea7b-402e-ae26-6bc89e07791a
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment.
```

This means I didn't set up HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR, And In my launch codes :

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" HADOOP_CONF_IR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode client
```

I typed `HADOOP_CONF_IR` instead of `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` which caused the problem that Yarn client didn't launch successfully.